# Retain reference to dynamic child refs with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

How would I retain a reference to dynamic child refs with Reactjs. I have a master component which manages children. This component needs to have access to its child's state to determine if the each child component has completed a process which they are responsible for. The master component is not said to be complete unless all child components are complete.

I have attempted what the docs mention about a refs callBack The problem with this approach is that React does not pass the component reference as mentiond here  http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html in the Ref Callback Attribute section once the said component mounts.

Please see my sample script below which details my issue.

```
var App = React.createClass({

 registerComponent: function (comp){
    //logic to retain a reference to the component
    //The problem with this approach is that React does not pass the component reference as mentiond 
    //here  http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html in the he ref Callback Attribute //section. 
 },
 isComplete: function(){
    //check  all child components to see if the App is complete
    for (comp in this.refs){
        //if any component is not complete then the App as a whole is not complete
        if(!comp.state.complete){
            return false;
        } 
    }

   return true;
 },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="Container">
        {this.state.arrayOfdata.map(function(value){

          if(value === class1Value){

            return <class1 ref={this.registerComponent}/>;
          }
          else if (value === class2Value){

            return <Class2 ref={this.registerComponent} />
          }
          else if (value === class3Value){
            return <Class3 ref={this.registerComponent}/>
          }                  
        }.bind(this))}
      </div>
    );      
  }

});

var class1 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return {
      complete: false;
    }
  },
  render: function (){
    return(
      <span className="class1"/>
    )
  }
});

var class2 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return {
      complete: false;
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <span className="class2"/>

    );
  }
});

var class3 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return {
      complete: false;
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <span className="class3"/>
    );
  }
});

var AppHandle = React.render(<App/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

What might I be doing wrong? Is their a better way to achieve what I am attempting to with the this.refs array.

Comment: What type of event will trigger the state change from incomplete to complete?

Comment: @Mark A touch event which is managed by the child. Upon touch, the child's state changes form incomplete to complete. I want to ensure that all child components have received interaction from the user before proceeding to the next stage in the application cycle.

Comment: Are class(x)Values within the arrayOfdata unique?  from `if(value === class1Value)` in the map function, it seems as if these objects are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approach I would take.  Manage the completeness state for each component, and whether all components are complete in the `App` component and have a function `handleComplete` which you can pass as a callback via props. The specific implementation will depend on your data, but this should give you the basic idea:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {complete: [], arrayOfdata: [], allComplete: false}
  },
  //call initializeComplete after arrayOfdata has been loaded
  initializeComplete: function(){
    var complete = [];
    for (i in this.state.arrayOfdata){
      complete[i] = false;
    }
    this.setState({complete: complete})
  },
  checkAllComplete: function(complete){
    for (i in complete){
      if (complete[i] == false){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  },
  handleComplete: function(index){
    complete = this.state.complete;
    complete[index] = true;
    allComplete = this.checkAllComplete(complete);
    this.setState({complete: complete, checkAllComplete: allComplete});
  }, 
  render: function() {
    //this assumes you can get whether the object is class 1, 2 or 3 from some attribute of the data
    components = this.state.arrayOfdata.map(function(object){
      return <ClassComponent classType={object.classType} index={count} key={object.uniqueAttribute} handleComplete={this.handleComplete}/>;               
    }.bind(this));
    return(
      <div className="Container">
        <span> Master component {this.state.allComplete ? 'complete' : 'incomplete'} </span>
        {components}
      </div>
    );      
  }

});

var ClassComponent = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    this.props.handleComplete(this.props.index);
  },
  render: function (){
    return(
      <span className={this.props.classType} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('content'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the refs={callback} functionality is only available in React v0.13 as of the writing I was utilizing v0.12 thus, this functionality was not working. Honest mistake.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't use refs here, but you can accomplish this by other approaches, depending on the parameters of your data.

Comment: @Mark thank you for your input. Can I ask you to share how you would achieve this same functionality from a design perspective. I am still a bit new to React js. I would prefer not to start off with bad practices. :)